# JS HTML CSS: how to make a function dynamically repeat with different variables each time while not repeating the same variables inside de function

Tags: javascript, html, css

### Intertwining Functions

I've been trying to make functions different but both have have the same original function. 
Here are my selectors:

```
const popControl = document.getElementById("pop");
const popHeader = document.getElementById("header");
const popButton = document.getElementById("close");
const popTitle = document.getElementById("title");
const popBody = document.getElementById("body");

const popControl2 = document.getElementById("pop2");
const popHeader2 = document.getElementById("header2");
const popButton2 = document.getElementById("close2");
const popTitle2 = document.getElementById("title2");
const popBody2 = document.getElementById("body2");`
```

With all my id's selected, I create my first function, called **verifyPosition**:

```
function verifyPosition(circleLeftPosition, circleRightPosition, moveBy) {
   console.log(circleLeftPosition, circleRightPosition);
   if (circleLeftPosition == "550px" && circleRightPosition == "75px") {
      popButton.addEventListener("click", closePosition);
      openPosition();
   }
}
```

Now, I must create the other, malfunctioning func, **verifyPosition2**:

```
function verifyPosition2(circleLeftPosition, circleRightPosition, moveBy) {
       console.log(circleLeftPosition, circleRightPosition);
       if (circleLeftPosition == "550px" && circleRightPosition == "75px") {
          popButton2.addEventListener("click", closePosition2);
          openPosition2();
       }
    }
```

For some reason, my **verifyPosition2** does not work, and it does not matter what you put in it.
This brings me to my ***final questions***:

- Why is it not working?
- And how can I make it work?

Thanks and thanks all!


*Hint: **[!ch.edit]** tag means I have edited this question.*

Answer (score 0):

You may try the below approach

```js
function verifyPosition(circleLeftPosition, circleRightPosition, moveBy, selector_extension) {
    if (circleLeftPosition == "550px" && circleRightPosition == "75px") {
        const popButton = document.getElementById("close" + selector_extension);
        // Checkout the below code, if verifyPosition is called multiple times on same element, there is chance of setting multiple click events on popButton
        popButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) { return closePosition(e, selector_extension); });
        openPosition(selector_extension);
    }
}
function closePosition(e, selector_extension) {
    // access the required elements using `selector_extension`
}
function openPosition(selector_extension) {
    // access the required elements using `selector_extension`
}
```